# Should Chromium-Vanadium (Cr-V) sockets be stored lubricated?

Tags: tools, rust-proofing, rust

I just ordered the [TEKTON 3/8 Inch Drive Deep 6-Point Impact Socket Set, 37-Piece (1/4-1 in, 6-24 mm) on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09423DLR5), it was delivered with each socket heavily lubricated (with what looks like oil). There was a cardboard piece in between both ends of the case, and it was pretty wet. You can find the [data sheet for it here](https://www.tekton.com/3-8-inch-drive-deep-6-point-impact-socket-set-sid91403) which shows the set is made from [Chromium-Vanadium (Cr-V)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium-vanadium_steel). Does this need to be lubricated or stored lubricated? Ths spec sheet above also says,

- *"All pieces have a corrosion-resistant manganese phosphate coating."*

It sounds all the more like this shouldn't be neccessary, but I'm wondering why they did it then.

Comment: Black is traditional for impact sockets,  that's probably why they went with manganese phosphate finish

Comment: I'm not sure why my comment was removed. It was justification for my close vote. This is a matter of opinion. Oil is applied because of extended shipping and storage periods. Whether you retain such a coating is entirely up to you and your use case. "Corrosion resistant" is not "corrosion proof".

Answer (score 1):

I store all of the tools used on my car with a **very** thin layer of oil - usually after using them they get a bit dirty so wiping off with a clean rag leaves enough to protect them.

I do not clean them with degreaser and leave them "dry" and unprotected.

Note, many metal items that are subject to long transport or storage times are shipped with a protective coating, this includes brake discs as an example. This needs cleaning off before use.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question to Tekton myself. I was mainly interested in knowing if corrosion, and not galling, was the reason for this coating.

> Q: These sockets came coated with some kind of lubrication, what is it? What's the purpose of it anti-galling or anti-corrusion? Can it be removed?

Here was their response,

> A: This is Nate from Tekton. These impact sockets ship with a coat of lubricant as a corrosion prevention measure, and **we recommend that you maintain the sockets with a lubricating oil.** If you remove the lubricant, it will not affect the performance of the sockets, but it **will make them less resistant to rust.**

So I take it that galling is not a concern here.

Comment: Actually resistance to galling is improved by the phosphate coating because it retains an oil film. Q & T steels of moderate hardness ( such as your tools which I assume are roughly Rockwell 30 = 150,000 psi tensile) , are subject to galling under some conditions which your tools are unlikely to experience.  Overshare; Higher strength oil field casing threads are prone to galling if not similarly coated.

Answer (score 0):

The manganese phosphate ( "conversion") coating gives some corrosion protection for mild service. Tools are "mild" service , normally dry and oil coated. So they should be fine unless you use them in salt water. The Cr-V is an ordinary low alloy steel, so has about the same corrosion resistance as carbon steel.